# Django can't show Bokeh plot's through CloudFlare tunnel

Tags: django, https, bokeh, cloudflare, windows-server-2019

Have a **Django **website that was accessed through port forwaring in the router. Django lives in an **Windows server** and in a happy companion with a **Bokeh server**. Accessing the server ip to a dedicated port gave respons and Django got nice graphics from Bokeh.

So I bought a **domain** and accessed the Django site via a **Cloudflare** *Tunnel*, and the Django website can’t get any grapics from Bokeh anymore.

How should this be configured and what is best practic for this to work well through Cloudflare.

I'am stretching my skills a bit here.
Anybody who can help me solve this puzzle?

Best regards
Jon Helge

Thougth in the beginning that the problem were in Bokeh, so installed SSL to solve communication between DJango and Bokeh. Did not solve the problem
Tried to find out how Django and Bokeh communicates with each other but still not seen a drawing for how exchenge of data is done between them. But if we go localhost again all is functioning again.
A bit stuck om how to go further.